# how to set student_id in session from json data in react native app?

Tags: react-native

how to set student_id in device session from JSON data received from an API in a react native app?

```
{"data":{"user":"user1","pass":"123456","student_id":"54","name":"test","student_birthdate":"1981-10-10","student_roll_no":"303","student_standard":"7","student_phone":"1234567890"},"responce":true}

fetch('http://192.168.0.2/index.php/api/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          Userid: user,
          Upassword: pass
        })

      }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {


          //console.log('response object:',responseJson)



        }).catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AsyncStorage` module to save the data in your device storage.

Read more here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage

Example after receiving the response:

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem('session_key', student_id);
```

For retrieving the key, you can use the `getItem` method from AsyncStorage.

```
_retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('session_key');
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // Error retrieving data
  }
};
```

**EDIT:**

The data from your server seems stringified. You need to parse that data to JSON.

Try this:

```
const responseFromServer = JSON.parse(responseJson);
```

Now, `responseFromServer` should contain the data property. You can access it like this:

`responseFromServer.data.student_id`

Comment: showing - json parse error: unexpected identifier "object"